# Force a short circuit on a CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case, short-circuiting

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to work with to make it more efficient. Unfortunately it is currently potentially being used by many applications, so although my optimal solution would be rewrite it, I'm currently constrained by what is there.

Initially there are two input parameters, both VARCHAR. I need to make a comparison between the two to different datatypes based on the value of the first parameter. However, I'm getting conversion errors when they shouldn't exist. Example:

```
    PROCEDURE ProcedureName
        @SearchType VARCHAR(24)
        , @SearchID VARCHAR(100)
    AS

    BEGIN  
      SELECT  
        t1.*,  
        t2.*  
      FROM  
        TableOne t1  
        JOIN TableTwo t2  
      WHERE  
            (CASE  
                WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' THEN CAST(t2.guid AS VARCHAR(100))  
                WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' THEN t2.id  
                WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ANOTHERID' THEN t1.id  
            END)  
            =  
            (CASE  
                WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' THEN @SearchID  
                WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID'  
                    OR UPPER(@SearchType) ='ANOTHERID' THEN CAST(@SearchID AS INT)  
            END)
    END
```

The goal here is if the Search type is GUID, it will convert the guid column in the table and make a comparison to the input string. 
Since both ID fields in the database are int type columns, I'd like to convert the SearchID, which will have an underlying data type of integer when ID or ANOTHERID are passed in, to an integer type to match the native column type.
However, every time I try to run this with 'GUID' in @SearchType and a guid in @SearchID, I get this error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<@SearchID>' to data type int.

Shouldn't this case statement be short circuiting so no conversion to int should ever occur with this input? Can I force it to short circuit?

Comment: Remove all computations and conversions from `where` clause, declare three variables of appropriate types, assign them before `select` statement and use ready to compare vars in `where`. And put `option(recompile)` 'cause stored plan will not comfort you on next runs.

Comment: I've added the following to the procedure: 
`IF UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' OR UPPER(@SearchType) ='ANOTHERID' BEGIN SET @IntSearchID = CAST(@SearchID AS INT) END` 
I then make the comparison at the end with only one new variable, because the input variable is already a varchar, and the other two options are both int: 
WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' OR UPPER(@SearchType) ='ANOTHERID' THEN @IntSearchID 
However, I still get the conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the comparison between the two `CASE` expressions, but with each `CASE` expressions itself.

```
CASE  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' THEN CAST(t2.guid AS VARCHAR(100))  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' THEN t2.id  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ANOTHERID' THEN t1.id  
END
```

Remember that in a `CASE` expression, all returns must have the same data type. If not, then they will be converted to the data type with the higher precedence. In the `CASE` expression above, you have one `VARCHAR` and two `INT`. Since `INT` has a higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the result of the first `WHEN` gets converted to `INT` and an error is produced:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type
>   int.

To fix this, you can convert the other two `INT` to `VARCHAR`:

```
(CASE  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' THEN CAST(t2.guid AS VARCHAR(100))  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' THEN CAST(t2.id AS VARCHAR(100))
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ANOTHERID' THEN CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(100))
END)
=
(CASE  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' THEN @SearchID  
    WHEN UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID'  
        OR UPPER(@SearchType) ='ANOTHERID' THEN @SearchID
END)
```

Another option is to use a combination of `AND` and `OR` conditions:

```
WHERE
    (UPPER(@SearchType) = 'GUID' AND CAST(t2.guid AS VARCHAR(100)) = @SearchID)
    OR (UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ID' AND t2.id = CAST(@SearchID AS INT))
    OR (UPPER(@SearchType) = 'ANOTHERID' AND t1.id = CAST(@SearchID AS INT))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: I thought enter would take me to the next line, but instead it posted heh. The first suggestion was basically what was in place already. The concern from my DBA was that since the two tables are quite large, there's a lot of conversion from their native data types that needs to occur, potentially slowing down the query. The goal was to minimize the conversions by only running the calculation on the input variable. I wasn't able to get the second suggestion to work; it gave me the same error.